# Making a false argument when proving $cl(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i) \subset \bigcup_{i\in I}cl(A_i)$

Tags: general-topology

I know that this is not true when I is infinite, but I think that my argument is valid even when I is infinite. Where is the flaw?:

Let $x\in cl(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)$ then for all $V \in V(x)$ (neighborhoods of x): $V \cap \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i=\bigcup_{i \in I}\left( V \cap A_i \right)\neq \emptyset$

Then $V \cap A_j\neq \emptyset$ for some $A_j \in \{A_i\}_{i\in I}$.
This means that $x\in cl(A_j)\subset \bigcup_{i\in I}cl(A_i)$

Comment: it's at "this means that" (and also "$A_j \in \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$" is not what you mean).

Comment: What if different $V$ intersect a different $A_j?$

Comment: @Matthew Towers I changed the $A_j\in \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ but I still don´t understand what you and other users are saying about $V$ changing (isn´t it true for all $V\in V(x)$?)

Comment: Ok I get it now, thanks everyone.

Comment: You showed that $(\forall V \in \mathcal V(x))(\exists j \in I)(V \cap A_j \neq \varnothing)$, which is very different from $(\exists j \in I)(\forall V \in \mathcal V(x))(V \cap A_j \neq \varnothing)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A_{n}=\{\frac 1n\}$ then for any neighborhood of $0,$ there are infinitely many $A_j$ contained in that neighborhood, but no $A_j$ is contained in all neighborhoods of $0.$

You need to show that there is one $j$ such that $A_j\cap V\neq\emptyset$ for all neighborhoods $V$ of $x.$ You've shown that for every $V$, there is a $j.$ That is a very different result.

---

In short notation, this is the difference between: $\exists j\forall V$ and $\forall V\exists j.$

For example:

> (1) For all natural numbers $n,$ there exists a natural number $m$ such that $m^2\leq n<(m+1)^2.$

> (2) There exists a natural number $m$ such that for all natural numbers $n,$ $m^2\leq n<(m+1)^2.$

(1) is true, (2) is definitely not.

Answer (score 1):

You have only shown that $A_j$ has nontrivial intersection with $V$, but when $V$ varies, $j$ might have to change.